# facebook email permission granted by the user does not get correct email

Tags: php, facebook

I'm having the issue with some facebook accounts. User granted email permission so I get from facebook back user info containing email. Checked with user he does have an email saved but instead of getting the actual email my app gets some weird app+e7mq0tl2e9.1atcj2t.9af3a401e9285e669c0480d3c4aa5fbe@proxymail.facebook.com

any thoughts why am I getting this instead of the actual user's email ?

Thank you in advance!

---

why am I asking this because based on the user's email I save his username (everything before '@') - but when I don't get the real user email I should probably force user to enter his email and username. In general Is there any useful articles or documentation regarding facebook and my website application interaction. For me the problem is once user sings up via facebook to correctly save the unique identifier for the user so next time user decides to Log in he can type in username and password (or still use facebook login which I assume will be the same as facebook sign up). But with sign up via facebook user does not specify his password so I need to generate/ask user to enter it...

Comment: Post here the scope you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook users can opt to use an anonymized e-mail address provided by Facebook when authenticating with scope=email. E-mails to that address will be passed to their actual e-mail.

This has the benefit of being disabled when the user removes your app (very handy for potentially spammy apps like Zynga games). You can't disable this, and you should treat them as legitimate e-mails.

Comment: thanks for the answer. so there is no way for me to obtain an actual email unless user disables that anonymizing feature? if so is this email app+e7mq0tl2e9.1atcj2t.9af3a401e9285e669c0480d3c4aa5fbe@proxymail.facebook.com just coded by facebook, so if I send the email to it the user gets email to their actual email?

Comment: Yes, the user will get those e-mails, and there's (deliberately) no way to get the e-mail it redirects to (other than asking the user to enter it in a form or something).

Comment: why am I asking this because based on the user's email I save his username (everything before '@') - but when I don't get the real user email I should probably force user to enter his email and username. In general Is there any useful articles or documentation regarding facebook and my website application interaction.

Comment: For me the problem is once user sings up via facebook to correctly save the unique identifier for the user so next time user decides to Log in he can type in username and password (or still use facebook login which I assume will be the same as facebook sign up). But with sign up via facebook user does not specify his password so I need to generate/ask user to enter it...

Comment: Just give them a "log in with Facebook" button and be done with it.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point to using facebook signing is so the user doesn't have to enter their username and password (as they have already done it with facebook.)
In your case, the next time they want to login, they'll click the "facebook" button, and you'll authenticate them with facebook. If they are already logged into facebook, they won't need to enter a password. So don't ask them for a password, or for a username for that matter.

If you want them to have a username and password on your site, then don't bother with doing a facebook login.

For identification purposes use one of the facebook id's that facebook will give you.